# Off canvas dialog using a button

Tags: 8, forms, javascript, ajax

I am trying to adapt the relatively new off canvas dialog introduced in Drupal 8.5.

It is suggested to use it with the Drupal Form-API and a link element like this:

```
$form['off_canvas'] = [
  '#title'      => 'Some title',
  '#type'       => 'link',
  '#url'        => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('some route'),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class'                => ['use-ajax'],
    'data-dialog-type'     => 'dialog',
    'data-dialog-renderer' => 'off_canvas',
    'data-dialog-options'  => \Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json::encode(['width' => '40%']),
  ],
  '#attached'   => [
    'library' => [
      'core/drupal.dialog.ajax',
    ],
  ],
];
```

This works pretty straight forward and out of the box, but for a very special use case I need to attach an AJAX-callback with a button element which is not possible using a link element when looking at the Drupal form API specifications.

This is what I got trying to use a button element and a callback with off canvas dialog functionality:

```
$form['some_button'] = [
  '#type'     => 'button',
  '#value'    => 'some value',
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [
      'core/drupal.dialog.ajax',
    ],
  ],
  '#ajax'     => [
    'callback' => '::some_callback',
  ],
];
```

Callback function goes here:

```
public function some_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();

  $title = 'Some title';

  $content = '<div>Some content</div>';
  $options = [];
  $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenOffCanvasDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
  return $response;
}
```

The funny thing is: once the off canvas dialog is initialized using `$form['off_canvas']` it works on both elements for `$form['off_canvas']` and `$form['some_button']`. On pageload it uses the old dialog for `$form['some_button']` and the new off canvas dialog for `$form['off_canvas']`.

So this must be an initialization problem for `$form['some_button]`. But I can not get this to work with the off canvas dialog at pageload and documentation for the new off canvas functionality is quite rare.

I tried to tell `$form['some_button']` to use off canvas as a parameter in a lot of ways, but it does not work. I guess I missed something here.

Can you guys give me a hint how to make this work from the very start using a button with an Ajax callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting back to this issue I did notice the strange behaviour is gone after upgrading to the latest Drupal 8.6.3. All works as expected even using a button.

I am not able to reproduce the behavior/error from above.

Answer (score 0):

How do I adapt this to open off-canvas dialog from javascript/jquery? I've tried the Drupal.dialog script which only opens normal dialogs. I've also seen the Drupal.offCanvas {} script - which is largely undocumented.
Any pointers please?